# One-to-many relationship getting error in Entity Framework Core when trying to insert data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to add data to one-to-many relationship tables. But there is an exception.

There are two tables:

1. Post
2. Attachment

The Post has many Attachment but one Attachment has one unique post. I'm going to try:

1. Adding records to the `Post` table, then after that
2. using that post-Id. update the `Attachment` table

Here is the exception thrown

> InvalidOperationException: The property 'Id' on entity type 'Posts' has a temporary value. Either set a permanent value explicitly or ensure that the database is configured to generate values for this property.
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.CommandBatchPreparer.Validate(ModificationCommand modificationCommand)
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.CommandBatchPreparer.d__8.MoveNext()
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(Tuple`2 parameters)
>
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 entries)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 entriesToSave)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges()
>          at GradChat.Data.Repo.PostRepository.PostRepo.AddPost(Posts post) in C:\Users\kokuadmin\source\repos\GradChat\GradChat.Data.Repo\PostRepository\PostRepo.cs:line 27'

And here the my `OnModelCreating()`

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{    
      modelBuilder.Entity<Posts>()
          .HasOne(p => p.User)
          .WithMany(c => c.Posts)
          .HasForeignKey(p => p.Id);    

      modelBuilder.Entity<Attachment>()
          .HasOne(p => p.Posts)
          .WithMany(c => c.Attachment)
          .HasForeignKey(p => p.Id);    
    }    
}
```

And here are the two entity classes :

```
public class Attachment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public string FileName { get; set; }    
    public string FileTye { get; set; }    
    public virtual Posts Posts { get; set; }    
    public int PostId { get; set; }    
}

public class Posts
{     
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public string Title { get; set; }    
    public string Content { get; set; }    
    public virtual User User { get; set; }    
    public int UserId { get; set; }    
    public virtual ICollection<Attachment> Attachment { get; set; }    
}
```

I'm using Microsoft.EntityFramework.Core.SqlServer (2.0.1)

Comment: Where did u assigned foreign key of attachment entity in post model? like `public int AttachmentId {get;set;}` in post model

Comment: The Relationship is One post has many Attachment, But One Attachment has unique post

Comment: Visit here night be help you https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9552

Comment: Its not help for me

Comment: try to remove `public int PostId { get; set; }` from `Attachment` model bcoz it will be created automatically by EF Core

Comment: Still the same. I remove public int PostId { get; set; }

Comment: replace this `modelBuilder.Entity<Attachment>()
          .HasOne(p => p.Posts)
          .WithMany(c => c.Attachment)
          .HasForeignKey(p => p.Id); ` with  `modelBuilder.Entity<Attachment>()
          .HasOne(p => p.Posts)
          .WithMany(c => c.Attachment);` in `OnModelCreating` means remove `HasForeignKey` and also remove `postId` property from `Attachment` model

Comment: Add-migration and update database i got this exception System.InvalidOperationException: To change the IDENTITY property of a column, the column needs to be dropped and recreated.

Comment: I am new for the EF.

Comment: please provide your `AddPost` in `PostRepo`. so i can try from my side. add this method in post

Comment: public Posts AddPost(Posts post)
    {
       try
      {
        _context.Posts.Add(post);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return post;

      } catch(Exception e)
      {
        throw new Exception($"Post Not Added. {e}");
      }
    
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed This.

change the `OnModelCreating()`as this. Thanks for Help me. just change, `.HasForeignKey(p=> p.Id)` to `.HasForeignKey(p => p.UserId);`

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Posts>()
          .HasOne(p => p.User)
          .WithMany(c => c.Posts)
          .HasForeignKey(p => p.UserId);

      modelBuilder.Entity<Attachment>()
        .HasOne(p => p.Posts)
        .WithMany(c => c.Attachment);
```

Comment: glad to hear that u have get rid from your problem :)

Comment: Thanks for the help me. :)